# How to obtain a better approach in reading file?

Tags: c#, .net

I just have a function here that caller wants number of bytes and then it returns the bytes but if there are not enough bytes in file it should return an smaller array. is there better approach to do this? I mean not getting 2 array and use `BlockCopy`?

```
byte[] GetPartialPackage(string filePath, long offset, int count)
{
    using (var reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        reader.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] tempData = new byte[count];
        int num = reader.Read(tempData, 0, count);
        byte[] tempdata = new byte[num];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(tempData, 0, tempdata, 0, num);
        return tempdata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the count based on the length of the stream to shorten it if necessary.

```
byte[] GetPartialPackage(string filePath, long offset, int count)
{
    using (var reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        reader.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int avaliableCount = Math.Min(count, (int)(reader.Length - offset));
        byte[] tempData = new byte[avaliableCount];
        int num = reader.Read(tempData, 0, avaliableCount);
        return tempData;
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about the seeking part?!

Comment: also it stills use 2 array and the `BlockCopy` Method!

Comment: Sorry, just updated to take the offset into account. It only uses 1 array and doesn't use block copy...

Comment: @lan : I want to read a range of bytes in a file in range [offset, offset+count-1].

Comment: @HPT: Which part of the code above doesn't work? It seeks the offset, it works out the the available length, decides if the count needs shortening to the avaliable length (modifiedCount), creates a byte array, reads the data into it and returns it....

Comment: @lan: I wrote the comment just before you've edited the answer. it works man. unless it shoul be `return tempData` and `int readerLength = (int)reader.Length - (int)offset;`

Comment: I just modified it slightly to do the calculation then the cast, and moved onto one line. And yes, should be return tempData

Answer (score 0):

This will only allocate one byte array:

```
byte[] GetPartialPackage(string filePath, long offset, int count)
{
    using (var reader = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        reader.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int actualCount = Math.Min(count, reader.Length - offset);
        byte[] tempData = new byte[actualCount];
        reader.Read(tempData, 0, actualCount);        
        return tempdata;
    }
}
```

Note, however, that according to MS documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx, a FileStream might actually read less bytes than requested even if the end of stream hasn't been reached.